# What to consider before taking a physics course (given a mathematical background)?

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, education

I'm a Computer Engineering major, but when I was in high school I was a very poor student.  I didn't pay attention and I didn't think I was capable of succeeding in classes like Math and Science so I just didn't care.  I'm much older now and a bit wiser, and because I'm back in school, I realize I may have some potential.

I've always loved science and math but never appreciated it.  I left high school knowing only pre-algebra.  Now 8 years later I taught myself Algebra through reading and practice, and started attending a community college and placed directly into their Pre-calc class without any Algebra classes.  I successfully passed Pre-Calc, Calculus 1 and currently in Calculus 2 all with A's.

I've never taken a Physics course before, but I'm extremely interested in the topic.  Will my success in Math translate into success with my upcoming physics courses (calculus based physics is where I'll be starting)?

Is there anyway to prepare to learn physics so that I have a higher chance of succeeding in the course?  How much of understanding physics is just natural ability?

Comment: Why don't you grab a book and try to do some exercises?

Comment: @jinawee I will do that, I just don't know enough about physics to know where to start.  My question is really about understanding how math and physics relate to one another when it comes to ones ability to succeed.

Comment: I think that you've got the ability, but the best thing is to get a physics background.

Comment: That strongly depends on the field. Theoretical physics needs much more math (especially advanced maths - still, many mathematicians have problems with it), experimental physics less math. If you are interested in phenomenology, you won't need too much math, in courses, however, you'll likely be confronted with typical quantitative questions, which means being good in maths can help you.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is not really opinion based. I see a person considering to take a physics course, explaining his situation and asking for advice, how to better prepare for the course, and whether he has necessary prerequisites for such an undertaking. It is a soft question indeed. I do think however, that both the title and the replies focus on probably more interesting question of how does math help a physicist, which biases the original question. One suggestion to improve the question would be to change its title. The question is not bad and should not be closed.

Comment: This question ... really isn't of the type we deal with on this site. It's broad and not really about physics concepts. You may wish to see [ask] and the relevant page on the [help/dont-ask] for more details on this. Sorry about this. You may have some luck discussing this in [chat] instead, there aren't many rules about chat.

Comment: @Manishearth, well, it is not my question. But I happened to answer it, because I thought it might be useful to many people. The question is not broad, as I have argued, because it describes a specific situation. It is indeed not about physics concepts. However, I have not found in both your links that questions should always be about physical concepts. For me this question is somewhat similar to a question about existing literature and that kind of questions, which are perfectly normal on this site. Therefore, I would ask you to give specific arguments for closing this question or to open it.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick See [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to tell for sure, physics (especially theoretical) is, however, largely dependent on mathematics so good knowledge of mathematics will certainly help. There is, nevertheless, a certain distinction to be made:

Mathematics is purely abstract while physics deals with applying this abstract apparatus to our real world observations. In other words, in physics, mathematics is used just as a tool for understanding our world with mathematics being the **means**. Mathematics, on the other hand, is focused on studying this abstract language and it is the **ends**. Nobody here (except for maybe you) can judge which of these fields suits you better.

There are people for whom mathematics is interesting for its own inner beauty. Mathematical thinking is clear and logic and some people find it appealing. Physics, on the other hand, requires taking this nice and complex mathematical language and making it suitable for a given physical problem. That often requires crude generalisations and making lots of approximations that, to someone, might lack the clarity of pure mathematics. For such people, mathematics is a better choice.

But there are also people who can understand mathematics, but it is a bit too abstract for them. They might need a clear picture behind mathematical concepts that mathematics by itself cannot provide. For such people, physics can be much more appealing because of its accent on real world providing this simple picture.

There is, naturally, also a lot of people in between who can enjoy both mathematics in physics (but possibly one a bit more than the other). Without all context, it is impossible for anyone to judge, into which of these group you belong. The best way to find out is to try and see. Just remember: there are lots of fields in physics and some might be of more interest to you than others. So if, at first, physics seems a bit boring, you might just need to find a different field. And if none of the fields in physics really suit you, that's alright, too; you can just stick to the math.